# What's with the huge supernova-like explosions in anime?

Tags: tropes

Why do they tend to occur so often in anime?

I'm not really a fan nor knowledgeable, but just curious is there any background behind this.

Here are some examples of what I mean:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3swylpHp8gs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9N-BuufhyU

Comment: it would be great if you could give an example of what exactly you mean

Comment: It would also be best if you justify your claim of "often". Most of the anime I watch have no explosions.

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko edited to include examples

Comment: This question is manifestly silly. It boils down to "explosions look cool"; everything else in the answers that have been given so far is fluff to pad out this simple fact.

Answer (score 6):

**Why explosions in general are popular:**

It's not much of a mystery & it mostly comes down to two things:

- Budget - it's cheaper to animate an explosion of a building than destroy a set in a movie.
- Genres - The most popular anime are usually shounen & action based. Predictably, explosions are something that that audience likes. You won't find many explosions in the romance genres. Western action film love explosions too.

---

**The blinding light of large explosions:**

[image] [image]

I would say it's a safe guess that this is inspired by a nuclear explosion. The gif below is captured with a good camera, but many clips of nuclear explosion have intensely bright light that the camera cannot record properly - resulting in an almost whiter-than-white colour.

[image]

> Time comes, and this tremendous flash out there is so bright that I duck, and I see this purple splotch on the floor of the truck. I said, "That's not it. That's an after-image." So I look back up, and I see this white light changing into yellow and then into orange. Clouds form and disappear again--from the compression and expansion of the shock wave.
>
> Finally, a big ball of orange, the center that was so bright, becomes a ball of orange that starts to rise and billow a little bit and get a little black around the edges, and then you see it's a big ball of smoke with flashes on the inside, with the heat of the fire going outwards.
>
> All this took about one minute. It was a series from bright to dark, and I had seen it. I am about the only guy who actually looked at the damn thing--the first Trinity test. Everybody else had dark glasses, and the people at six miles couldn't see it because they were all told to lie on the floor. I'm probably the only guy who saw it with the human eye.
>
> Finally, after about a minute and a half, there's suddenly a tremendous noise--BANG, and then a rumble, like thunder-- and that's what convinced me. Nobody had said a word during this whole thing. We were all just watching quietly. But this sound released everybody--released me particularly because the solidity of the sound at that distance meant that it had really worked.
>
> The man standing next to me said, "What's that?"
> I said, "That was the Bomb."

*Extract from Richard Feynman, American physicist's biography*

Obviously Japan has been influenced a lot from nuclear weaponry after the bombings of [Nagasaki & Hiroshima in WW2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_bombings_of_Hiroshima_and_Nagasaki). Because of this it finds itself in a lot of Japanese works. In fact, one of the first manga to be translated to english was [Barefoot Gen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barefoot_Gen) - a survivor's tale from the Hiroshima bombings.

Nuclear energy's intense devastation is also immense power and it's one of the most powerful representations an artist could use to show the strength of an explosion/character.

Many successful works have used this technique, including Dragonball Z, Akira, etc and because of this, their usage has grown even further.

**'Star' Explosions**

Attempt 3 at trying to understand what your question means - this time I presume you mean the star-like explosions that are in your videos.

[image]

Studio Gainax has these effects as a sort of signature, originally appearing in the very successful Neon Genesis Evangellion.  Evangellion has many religious references - including their cross-shaped explosions.

[image]

Since then, the studio's work has used these often as explosions. Studio Trigger, which was founded by gainax ex-employees also use the feature a lot - see Kill la Kill for example.

Gainax is responsible for modern usage from their own usage of the explosion type - However, [Space Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_space_opera_media#Anime) was a popular genre in the 80s, causing many shows to be set in space - and also be action-packed, leading to many explosions - some of which being supernova-like. Gundam for instance is one particular show of note from this period.

**Further reading**

- There are countless resources on the WW2 bombings
- I recommend looking at the [TVTropes Page on Fade to
  White](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FadeToWhite) - which is often how the trope is used.
- [Space Opera genre on TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpaceOpera)

Comment: I meant Supernova explosion, not nuclear explosion. I thought you can't understand Supernova other than Supernove... Funny. Check this out, perhaps it will help to understand: https://youtu.be/3swylpHp8gs?t=28 . And this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova

Comment: I am describing bright-light explosions - not just ones on the ground, but in the air too, as a sphere. maybe I should have had a gif of that too.  It's possible I just haven't seen this type of explosion much

Comment: yeah, but that does not address the question.

Comment: @Zloj what about now? perhaps if you edit your question to be more specific (stills rather than videos) it would be easier for users to answer

Comment: It already says `supernova-like`. How much more specific can one be about supernova explosion than saying supernova explosion?...

Answer (score 5):

While your question is poorly qualified and given no bounds, it is probably false. However, in the interest of answering the question, we shall assume you are talking about the subset of ***Shounen***/***Action*** anime.

I'd like to expand @ToshinouKyouko's points of *Budget* and *Genre* and include  several other considerations for your question.

- **Default subject matter for the genre**

  The default subject matter for Shounen is fighting. When fighting,
  something is bound to give. Explosions are therefore commonplace,
  especially when the main concept of the show is a super power, mecha,
  or magic, etc. All these tend to use some kind of power or powerful
  weapon to destroy the opponent.
- **Solution for elimination**

  It is a "clean" solution for killing an opponent. There is no
  blood/gore and          there are no corpses to clean up. Note that
  the default audience for the genre tends to be younger. There is no
  problem with having less questionable methods especially if the
  audience may be squeamish or if they are considering censorship
  issues. Either way it is the most basic and clean solution, to make
  them disappear.
- **Power Creep**

  As the story goes on, enemies get more powerful, and so does our
  hero. The easiest way of showing that when they fight is increasingly
  bigger explosions. The fact that our hero is stronger, means that he
  should be able to make a bigger Fireball, for example. A bigger
  fireball makes a bigger explosion as it stands to reason, does it
  not? The stronger enemy would also be capable of such feats of the
  same scale, and clashing with them would of course yield an explosion
  that is at least twice as big! This can be easily observed from anime
  where the fights can destroy worlds.
- **Anime as a medium**

  Anime is freeform storytelling. They are able to achieve more things
  than a traditional movie would because they can. Anime just need to
  animate something out and it exists. Movies are increasingly moving
  towards a lot of CG scenes because of this. Even explosions are
  getting done in CG more often too. Because it is so free, so unbound,
  they can do whatever they want. In the case of Shounen, this results
  in explosions, even on a scale of universes, if they so choose.
- **Popularity of explosions**

  Of course one cannot exclude the fact that their target audience may
  simply love seeing an explosion. Fireworks are simply popular, some
  even like to see stuff explode in real life. It is also popular for
  movies. If it is so popular, why not include it in anime, from the
  previous point, they can do it better. They can control the look and
  the size and make it however their audience may like it. I'm sure as
  a shounen anime watcher, perhaps nothing could please them more
  having the "bad guy" blow up and destroyed.

Comment: Everything except Popularity of explosions can be removed and then the answer will probably explain one possible reason.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Why aren't the rest reasons?

Comment: @Tyhja He's just being snarky, ignore.